# Merge two arrays of object by object key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I want to extend my array of objects by items from another array of objects by identic ids

I try to make it with array.map function but result is not as i expected
My arrays:

```json
[
  {
    "objectId": 330,
    "items": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 20,
        "orderId": 103
      },
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 22,
        "orderId": 120
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectId": 250,
    "items": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 45,
        "orderId": 99
      },
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 13,
        "orderId": 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

my second array looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Toilet",
    "price": 100,
    "id": 45
  },
  {
    "name": "TV",
    "price": 800,
    "id": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "Book",
    "price": 20,
    "id": 13
  }
]
```

and result merged array i need:

```json
[
  {
    "objectId": 330,
    "items": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 20,
        "orderId": 103,
        "values": {
          "name": "TV",
          "price": 800,
          "id": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 22,
        "orderId": 120,
        "values": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectId": 250,
    "items": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 45,
        "orderId": 99,
        "values": {
          "name": "Toilet",
          "price": 100,
          "id": 45
        }
      },
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 13,
        "orderId": 100,
        "values": {
          "name": "Book",
          "price": 20,
          "id": 13
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to create merged array of objects. The spread operator `...` is used is used to crate new object with all properties of the original one. The `find` method is used to find  the needed item in `arr2` by `item.id` of `arr1`. If nothing is find  `null` is assigned to the `values` key.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    "objectId": 330,
    "items": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 20,
        "orderId": 103
      },
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 22,
        "orderId": 120
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "objectId": 250,
    "items": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 45,
        "orderId": 99
      },
      {
        "status": 0,
        "id": 13,
        "orderId": 100
      }
    ]
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    "name": "Toilet",
    "price": 100,
    "id": 45
  },
  {
    "name": "TV",
    "price": 800,
    "id": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "Book",
    "price": 20,
    "id": 13
  }
];

const mergedArr = arr1.map(obj => ({
  objectId: obj.objectId,
  items: obj.items.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    values: arr2.find(val => val.id === item.id) || null
  }))
}));


console.log(mergedArr)
```